# phonegap app says "store is undefined" with cordova-plugin-purchase

Tags: cordova, undefined, cordova-plugins, android-inapp-purchase

I added https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase to my first phonegap app and tried code from this sample app: https://github.com/Fovea/cordova-plugin-purchase-demo 
I tried different ways, but while debugging my app always tells me "store is not defined" or goes into "if(!windows.store)". Why?

```js
// Our application's global object
var app = {};

app.nonHostedContentUrl = "http://ge.tt/api/1/files/3JSfJhL2/0/blob?download";

//
// Constructor
// -----------
//

app.initialize = function() {
    //log('initialize');

    // Listen to the deviceready event.
    // Make sure the score of 'this' isn't lost.
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.bind(this.onDeviceReady), false);
};

//
// Methods
// -------
//

// deviceready event handler.
//
// will just initialize the Purchase plugin
app.onDeviceReady = function() {
    //log('onDeviceReady');
    this.initStore();
};

// initialize the purchase plugin if available
app.initStore = function() {

    if (!window.store) {
        alert('Store not available');
        return;
    }

    app.platform = device.platform.toLowerCase();
    //document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].className = app.platform;

    // Enable maximum logging level
    store.verbosity = store.DEBUG;

    // Enable remote receipt validation
    store.validator = "https://api.fovea.cc:1982/check-purchase";

    // Inform the store of your products
    //log('registerProducts');
    store.register({
        id:    'consumable1', // id without package name!
        alias: 'extra life',
        type:   store.CONSUMABLE
    });
}


// make sure fn will be called with app as 'this'
app.bind = function(fn) {
    return function() {
        fn.call(app, arguments);
    };
};

app.initialize();
```

my first try was:

```js
 function initializeStore() {

  if (!window.store) {
   alert('Window.Store not available');
   return;
  }
  
  if (!store) {
   alert('Store not available');
   return;
  }
  
  // Let's set a pretty high verbosity level, so that we see a lot of stuff
  // in the console (reassuring us that something is happening).
  store.verbosity = store.INFO;

  // We register a dummy product. It's ok, it shouldn't
  // prevent the store "ready" event from firing.
  store.register({
   id:    "myapp.inappid1",
   alias: "100 points",
   type:  store.CONSUMABLE
  });

  store.ready(function() {
   alert("\\o/ STORE READY \\o/");
  });

  store.refresh();
 }
 

 document.addEventListener('deviceready', initializeStore, false);
```

I also tried removing the plugin and add it from github, like told here: [Initialization Android In App Billing using cordova plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31507222/initialization-android-in-app-billing-using-cordova-plugin)

Some suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone else is searching for the answer: this plugin doesn't work in phonegap developer app! But it works when released.

Comment: Hi @Lilliput could you explain to me why this behavior? if this is the case, how can we debug before the app launch!